# How to retrieve carousel image and captions and opening it up as a modal upon click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to implement a carousel that opens up the image with the associated caption in a modal when the user clicks on the image.

So far, I am able to open up the image but not able to retrieve the caption as the script only looks for attribute within the img tag. Is there a way to also retrieve the h5 and p tag within the carousel-caption div container and pass it so that the modal receives it?

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="gallery-modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <img src="img/1.jpg" class="modal-img" alt="modal img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener("click",function (e){
   if(e.target.classList.contains("d-block")){
      const src = e.target.getAttribute("src");
      document.querySelector(".modal-img").src = src;
      const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('gallery-modal'));
      myModal.show();
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("d-block")) {
        const src = e.target.getAttribute("src");
        const captionDiv = e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;

        if (captionDiv) {
            const captionTitle = captionDiv.querySelector("h5");
            const captionText = captionDiv.querySelector("p");

            if (captionTitle && captionText) {
                document.querySelector(".modal-img").src = src;
                document.querySelector(".modal-title").innerText = captionTitle.innerText;
                document.querySelector(".modal-text").innerText = captionText.innerText;

                const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('gallery-modal'));
                myModal.show();
            } else {
                console.error("Caption elements not found.");
            }
        } else {
            console.error("Caption container not found.");
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="gallery-modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" class="modal-img" alt="modal img">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <p class="modal-text"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I realised if I just include .nextElementSibling, it will move down to the associated div class with the captions and from there I can apply a queryselector to retrieve the h5 and p tags.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the functionality you desire, you can modify your JavaScript code to retrieve the caption content associated with the clicked image and pass it to the modal.